# Python library for creation excel Pivot Charts

Tags: excel, python-3.x, charts, pivot

I've recently found out very nice looking pivot charts in excel with additional posibilities to filter them. Having dataframe in python ís there an option to create such a Pivot Chart automatically?

Comment: So are you looking for a library?

Comment: I would rather say a way to do it:) is there a method in pandas similar to pivot_table?